# Solving a simple 2nd order ODE with boundary values

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in the solution to the following 1-parameter family of 2nd order ODE:
$$(\lambda (xH' - H)^3 + 4(H')^2 (1-H') x^2)H'' - 4 H'(1-H')(xH'-H)(x+H')=0,$$

with $H(0) = 1$ and $H(1) = 0$. $\lambda < 0$ is the parameter.

I am interested in either analytic solution or proof that no analytic solutions exists. Uniqueness of solutions is also appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried simplifying it?

Comment: I have tried solving it using mathematica.

Comment: Some things which seem to be recurring all over the place: $(1-H')$, $(x+H')$, $(xH'-H)$, maybe we can find some function to substitute which makes all of those simpler.

Comment: Then you can break down into an equation system with writing the new functions in relations to each other. Also what do you mean by "analytic" solution? Expressibility in some specific class of functions?

Comment: I don't know how breaking it down into a system could make it more amenable to attack. Originally I did write it in terms of $a = (xH' - H)$, etc. Analyticity could mean anything expressible in closed form, using special functions etc.

Comment: Adding new unknowns can make it possible linearize the problem to make it attackable by systematic linear methods. Example: $f(x)^2 + f'(x)f(x) = k$, $g(x) = f(x)^2$, $g'(x) = 2f(x)f'(x)$, $ \Rightarrow g(x) + g'(x)/2 = k$ which is a nicer linear problem.

Comment: Here is the numerical solved (1-H) along with -H' and -H''. Let me know if you think the chance of "nice" closed form solution is low: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Saf9_IU45Ng/WRNYKwcHBkI/AAAAAAAAAX8/yn21n88TRGEXxFSLVfYkp3COetqcSC6hQCL0B/h215/2017-05-10.png

Comment: Maybe you can stress the uniqueness by adding some cost term / constraint to the numerical solver. For example trying to add $H'(0.5) = \lambda$ and see if it manages to find different solutions for some different $\lambda$. You can start with sampling $\lambda$ from the solution found and doing small displacements of it : $\pm \epsilon$.

Comment: @mathreadler Interesting. Thanks for the suggestion. So far the solutions all make sense in the context of the original Euler Lagrange constraint problem from which the ODE arises. But certainly can't rule out saddle points.